# Load runner Recording Isssue in Oracle EBS

Tags: loadrunner

I am doing the POC on Oracle EBS application by using Load runner for performance testing.While recording, I am able to log into application and open the oracle forms by clicking on one responsibility but as soon a my Oracle forms gets open the recording gets stopped from backhand which i came to know when i stopped the recording.

I am using multiple protocols as Web-Http and Oracle NCA but still i am not able to record the oracle steps.Below is the configuration i am using.

Java version -: JRE 1.8_201
Vugen version -: 12.60

Can anyone helps me in knowing what extra i need to do from my end to record the oracle NCA steps while recording.

Thanks 
Bakul

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is a Oracle NCA protocol in LoadRunner, maybe you could try that one. You could also try TruClient protocol too.

Best.